# Is it possible to change ownership of an AWS KMS CMK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

I suspect the answer is "no" but cannot find that explicitly stated, so thought I would ask...

The application I had in mind is that I would like to create a Customer Managed Key in AWS for one of our customers by default so that they do not have to incur the overhead of creating their own AWS Account, and DevOps staff to manage the CMK.

Later, if the customer does want to take ownership of the key, it would be easier to simply reassign ownership that to have to re-encrypt all their data with a new key.

Comment: Explicitly stating all operations that are not possible is itself impossible because there are infinitely many things you cannot do and only very limited things you can do. You cannot transfer ownership of AWS resource, not buckets, not queues, not lambdas, not roles, not ec2 instances, not cmks. See e.g. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/account-transfer-rds/ and https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/transfer-aws-account/

Comment: Thanks... you should have posted as an answer... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can create separate AWS accounts easily by contacting support and they will be billed to your master account.  You could then create the KMS key there and establish the right KMS key policy to permit them access to use it.  If you ever want to 'transfer' that KMS key, you could transfer that entire AWS account to them.  More details on that here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/transfer-aws-account/